# How can I get superuser's information?

Tags: django

I am making Django app.I want to use superuser's data in the codes.
I registered name&email&password.Usually User's data can be gotten like

```
user = User.objects.get(id=1)
name = user.name
```

but how can I get superuser's data?

Comment: `User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)`

Comment: @solarissmoke thank you for your comments.I wrote user codes like `user=User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)  print(user.name)` but  AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'name' error happens.

Comment: @solarissmoke what is wrong in my codes?whenI print out print(user),superuser's data can be gotten.

Comment: I have explained a bit more in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter superusers like this:

```
superusers = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)
```

You can have more than one superuser on a site, so this query will give you a queryset of superusers, not just one (you could do `.get()` if there was only one, but this would give you an error if there was more than one).

You can then inspect each superuser by iterating over them:

```
for user in superusers:
    print(user)
```